# What should i choose

Tags: solid-body-electric-guitars

## 1  I own a small instrument company and my guitars are make in China.

They offer to put Alnico pickups in as an option. If you (meaning general public) were to order a guitar through me would most ask for this option over Ceramic?
Thanks, for any help

## 2 I try to keep my guitar room at 45% humidity.  I often find that I have condensation on them.  Will this interfere with the electronics in my electric guitars?

Answer (score 1):

Some will prefer Alnico magnets, while others will choose the ceramic magnets. The reason for offering both types is because there is a market and preference for both. You might consider stocking some of both and pay attention to where your customer demand is.
 Concerning your humidity level, I can only imagine condensation being a problem when the room temperature drops well below 60 degrees F. Condensation can cause damage to electrical parts on guitars and any other instruments and amplifiers. What is good for the wood is not necessarily good for the metal and electrical parts. Along with the humidity, you need to keep the room temperature warm enough to be comfortable for you and your instruments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are selling "no-name" Chinese instruments with "no-name" components, you might ask whether the people who are going to buy them will care about anything except the price and the colour of the body.

If somebody plans to spend $500 or more just for a replacement set of pickups, it's a valid question to consider. If they are spending $50 on a complete guitar, not so much! (And if they are getting a guitar which has been stored with condensation on it, they are buying junk whoever made it and whatever price it is, IMO).